# Everything within Photoshop appears smaller?

Tags: resolution, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I'm on Windows with Photoshop CS6 Extended. Everything in the program (fonts, canvas size, etc.) is just a little smaller than it should be. I have a feeling this has something to do with the program settings not matching up to my screen resolution but I really have no idea. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the scaling? At Windows settings, of course.

Comment: Find [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027860/windows-10-view-display-settings) how to change the size of text, icons, apps etc.

Comment: @spike_66 everything else on my windows system is of scale, it seems that just photoshop has the scaling issue.

Comment: @MichaelBay everything else on my windows system is of scale, it seems that just photoshop has the scaling issue.

Comment: What is the resolution of your monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences,

Interface,

Change 'UI Font Size' - (This must have been set to tiny.) Make this Small or Medium.